# Array to string error when creating a new model

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.5.2 and I'm using the ACL component in my application. I want to modify the table aros_acos, so I made a Model called **Permission.php** which contains the following:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Permission extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'permission';
    public $useTable = 'aros_acos';

}
```

But when I go to my permissionsController in the browser I'm getting this error:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 458]

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

SQL Query: check
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. Could somebody help me?

Comment: would be helpful to have the code of the controller to see what is triggering the error.

Comment: I'm not calling this model in the controller code.

Comment: then why are you including the code for your model if the controller is throwing the error? Btw, must be a problem with `public $name = 'permission';`, change it to `public $name = 'Permission';` or don't put that line at all.

Comment: Because the Permission model is automatically called when you browse the controller. I tried your suggestion but it returns the same error. Maybe it has something deal with that in the Cake folder already a Permission model exists?

Comment: try to change the name of your model then, there's a class in cake lib that has the same name http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Permission.html

Comment: What exactly is that you want to modify which cannot be done using the ACL component or the (as mentioned by @Nunser) existing `Permission` model?

Comment: in that view show this error? do you could provide the controller and view?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this line:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
```

The `extends` function already includes `AppModel`

and change the name from this:

```
public $name = 'permission';
```

to this:

```
public $name = 'Permission';
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It returns the same error for me.. Maybe it has something deal with that in the Cake folder already a Permission model exists?